# Does Ruby Yard have a feature comparable to RDoc :include: tag?

Tags: ruby, rdoc, yard

RDoc has the :include: tag (see the bottom of [this page](http://rdoc.sourceforge.net/doc/files/README.html)) that will take in an arbitrary text file and format as if it was indented wherever the include begins. This is a great way to pull in source code for documentation examples.

Does [Yard](http://yardoc.org/) have a similar tag or feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently YARD only supports embedding documentation from other object docstrings in the form:

```
class Foo
  # Docstring here
  def method; end

  # Here is some more docs and {include:Foo#method}
  def bar; end
end
```

File inclusion was vaguely planned but it was never really requested before, so it wasn't high priority. If you want to open an issue on http://github.com/lsegal/yard/issues -- we can make sure it gets tracked and added for the upcoming 0.7.0 release.

Comment: * 10 years later * I've tried that snippet in modern RubyMine and it seems to be ignoring {include} tag completely. It is rendered as plain text, without "Docstring here" injection